# How to add a custom field to a layout section in SalesForce via the API

Tags: api, layout, salesforce, custom-fields

I am creating a Java API integration tool, that on start up will create a new custom filed if it doesn't exist for Lead & Contact. After a bit of searching I have found how to do this.
Now the next bit on the list, is to get the newly created field into the "Lead Information" or "Contact Information" layout.

I have looked in the [metadata api docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/api_rest.pdf) and cannot find an example, either using Java or plain SOAP messages. I have searched online, in most of the forums, and sample code bases I can find, with no success.

So if anyone one is able to supply an example either through Java or SOAP, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Did you look at the Layout component in the Metadata API Doc? There is an example at the bottom of http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/meta_layouts.htm

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried myself but you should be able to do that using the Update API call from Metadata API. For more information: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add a field to a layout.  You have to first get the existing layout and then add the field to it and then update the layout.
A layout is a complex object made up of other objects representing the sections and then the rows, etc.
I recommend first retrieving a layout via either the SOAP or Metadata API and once you've looked at the result, it should be clearer on how you can parse it and inject your additional row and field.